# expose the next/prev pointer in a generic list

Tags: java, generics

I want to have a generic doubly linked list where, when I create a List (where point has getX() & getY()), it now also has getPrev() and getNext() where prev/next are the previous/next object in the list.

This is a piece of cake to do if I write my own list code (which I do **not** want to do). Is there a way to do this with generics or some other library? Basically, rather than have an invisible container object that points to my point as well as a prev/next pointer, can I push that prev/next pointer to my object?

thanks - dave

Comment: Not unless you can inherit from a common base class, or have all your classes re-implement the getNext()/getPrev() functions of a common interface, is that acceptable solutions ?

Comment: Any specific reason you don't want to roll your own?

Comment: @nos I think that's how it must work - that the templated class must implement an interface that has previous() and next(). Is there a class that does this?

Comment: @turbo - I'd prefer an existing library because it will be rock solid & fast (if it is in the runtime somewhere). And that saves me time coding.

Comment: Valid reason, just curious.

Answer (score 2):

[java.util.LinkedList<E>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is already a doubly-linked list. `LinkedList.listIterator(int)` returns a `ListIterator<E>` object, which exposes the methods `next()` and `previous()`, among other things.

Comment: The problem is the list object exposes next & previous. I want my objects contained in the list to provide the next & previous methods.

Comment: @DavidThielen, In that case, without some reflection shenanigans to gain access to the private class `LinkedList.Entry`, your only option is to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can with java.util.LinkedList

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList

Have a look at line 95. The class only keeps track to the head of the list so each call to getNext and getPrev will always run in O(N) time never O(1)

You can't use LinkedList (in either a is a or has relationship) to implement getNext and getPrev methods and  have those methods run in constant time. As the entity class is private in `LinkedList` and so is the pointer to the head of the list. You can do it in O(n) like this `getNext(get(cursor++));` as get takes O(n) time. There are ways you could do it (refletion) but you are better off to just write your own implementation of a linked list or live with the `ListIterator`.

Comment: `LinkedList` has no `getNext`/`getPrev` method, so the fact that it only tracks the head is a non-issue. The only public-facing next/prev relating to `LinkedList` comes from the `ListIterator` interface, which is correctly implemented (in a private inner class of `LinkedList`, `ListIter`).

Comment: I know it doesn't have a getNext, getPrev, nor should it. That is what the ListIterator is for.

Comment: If you understand the purpose and use of the iterator, then I don't understand why you're talking about next/prev being O(N) operations. The source you linked to shows `ListIter` with O(1) operations for both methods.

Comment: The edits are certainly better. I'm still not sure I understand why you're talking about implementing next/prev with `LinkedList` in O(N) time, when they're already implemented in O(1) time in the list's iterator; regardless, OP is apparently interested in the _elements_ of the list having next/prev, not the list itself, meaning he needs heavy reflection, or rolling his own class.

Comment: yes you are right, I though the OP wanted to implement next prev on the list not the elements. About the O(N) if you wanted to add to the `LinkedList` class the methods `next` and `prev` you could do it, it would just be a bad idea. When I was looking at the source I wanted to see if the head of the list was `protected` and accessible by the child.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Maybe you could mention subclassing `LinkedList` in there, to make it more clear what you're saying?